# Is there any way to edit programmatically nested tables in html file using BeatifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a table in a webpage with BeautifulSoup. I managed to put the text in a txt file.

However, some  contains multiple tables inside. I guess that the developers had some aesthetic directive and they couldn't edit the cell any other way to meet their requirements. I have many problems in scraping the tables the way they are, so i was wondering if there exists a way to programmatically edit the HTML in order to extrapolate the txt from those nested tables into the original  cell.

Here an example of what I mean.

**From a nested table like this**

```
<tr class="table">
             <td class="table" valign="top">
                <p class="tbl-cod">0403</p>
             </td>
             <td class="table" valign="top">
                <p class="tbl-txt">Buttermilk, curdled milk and&nbsp;cream, yoghurt, kephir and other fermented or acidified milk and&nbsp;cream, whether or not concentrated or&nbsp;containing added sugar or other sweetening matter or flavoured or&nbsp;containing added fruit, nuts or&nbsp;cocoa</p>
             </td>
             <td class="table" valign="top">
                <p class="tbl-txt">Manufacture in which:</p>
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                   <colgroup><col width="4%">
                   <col width="96%">
                   </colgroup><tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <td valign="top">
                            <p class="normal">—</p>
                         </td>
                         <td valign="top">
                            <p class="normal">all the materials of Chapter&nbsp;4 used are wholly obtained,</p>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                   <colgroup><col width="4%">
                   <col width="96%">
                   </colgroup><tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <td valign="top">
                            <p class="normal">—</p>
                         </td>
                         <td valign="top">
                            <p class="normal">all the fruit juice (except that of pineapple, lime or&nbsp;grapefruit) of heading&nbsp;2009 used is originating,</p>
                            <p class="normal">and</p>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                   <colgroup><col width="4%">
                   <col width="96%">
                   </colgroup><tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <td valign="top">
                            <p class="normal">—</p>
                         </td>
                         <td valign="top">
                            <p class="normal">the value of all the materials of Chapter&nbsp;17 used does not exceed 30&nbsp;% of the ex-works price of the product</p>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </td>
             <td class="table" valign="top">
                <p class="normal">&nbsp;</p>
             </td>
          </tr>
```

I would like to edit the HTML file in order to get

```
<tr class="table">
             <td class="table" valign="top">
                <p class="tbl-cod">0403</p>
             </td>
             <td class="table" valign="top">
                <p class="tbl-txt">Buttermilk, curdled milk and&nbsp;cream, yoghurt, kephir and other fermented or acidified milk and&nbsp;cream, whether or not concentrated or&nbsp;containing added sugar or other sweetening matter or flavoured or&nbsp;containing added fruit, nuts or&nbsp;cocoa</p>
             </td>
             <td class="table" valign="top">
                <p class="tbl-txt">Manufacture in which: all the materials of Chapter&nbsp;4 used are wholly obtained, — all the fruit juice (except that of pineapple, lime or&nbsp;grapefruit) of heading&nbsp;2009 used is originating, — the value of all the materials of Chapter&nbsp;17 used does not exceed 30&nbsp;% of the ex-works price of the product</p>
             </td>
             <td class="table" valign="top">
                <p class="normal">&nbsp;</p>
             </td>
          </tr>
```

from all the nested tables in the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that if your `html` be always like this.
Find all `columns` inside each `rows` and then check if the column has children `table`
Then get text of all the **P** tag w.r.t those columns and replace with `first P` tag text.
Then **decompose**() all the table tag from the column.

Code:

```
html='''<tr class="table">
             <td class="table" valign="top">
                <p class="tbl-cod">0403</p>
             </td>
             <td class="table" valign="top">
                <p class="tbl-txt">Buttermilk, curdled milk and&nbsp;cream, yoghurt, kephir and other fermented or acidified milk and&nbsp;cream, whether or not concentrated or&nbsp;containing added sugar or other sweetening matter or flavoured or&nbsp;containing added fruit, nuts or&nbsp;cocoa</p>
             </td>
             <td class="table" valign="top">
                <p class="tbl-txt">Manufacture in which:</p>
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                   <colgroup><col width="4%">
                   <col width="96%">
                   </colgroup><tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <td valign="top">
                            <p class="normal">—</p>
                         </td>
                         <td valign="top">
                            <p class="normal">all the materials of Chapter&nbsp;4 used are wholly obtained,</p>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                   <colgroup><col width="4%">
                   <col width="96%">
                   </colgroup><tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <td valign="top">
                            <p class="normal">—</p>
                         </td>
                         <td valign="top">
                            <p class="normal">all the fruit juice (except that of pineapple, lime or&nbsp;grapefruit) of heading&nbsp;2009 used is originating,</p>
                            <p class="normal">and</p>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                   <colgroup><col width="4%">
                   <col width="96%">
                   </colgroup><tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <td valign="top">
                            <p class="normal">—</p>
                         </td>
                         <td valign="top">
                            <p class="normal">the value of all the materials of Chapter&nbsp;17 used does not exceed 30&nbsp;% of the ex-works price of the product</p>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </td>
             <td class="table" valign="top">
                <p class="normal">&nbsp;</p>
             </td>
          </tr>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
for row in soup.find_all('tr',class_='table'):
    for col in row.find_all('td'):
        if col.findChildren("table"):
           #Get all the p tag text from col which contains table
           ptag_text=''.join([i.text for i in col.find_all('p')])
           #Get the first p tag and replace the value with previus value
           col.find('p').next_element.replace_with(ptag_text)
           for item in col.findChildren("table"):
                item.decompose()

print(soup)
```

**Output**:

```
<html><body><tr class="table">
<td class="table" valign="top">
<p class="tbl-cod">0403</p>
</td>
<td class="table" valign="top">
<p class="tbl-txt">Buttermilk, curdled milk and cream, yoghurt, kephir and other fermented or acidified milk and cream, whether or not concentrated or containing added sugar or other sweetening matter or flavoured or containing added fruit, nuts or cocoa</p>
</td>
<td class="table" valign="top">
<p class="tbl-txt">Manufacture in which:—all the materials of Chapter 4 used are wholly obtained,—all the fruit juice (except that of pineapple, lime or grapefruit) of heading 2009 used is originating,and—the value of all the materials of Chapter 17 used does not exceed 30 % of the ex-works price of the product</p>



</td>
<td class="table" valign="top">
<p class="normal"> </p>
</td>
</tr></body></html>
```

---

If you don't want those new lines then do .replace all new lines like below.

```
finalhtml=str(soup).replace('\n','')
print(finalhtml)
```

**Output**:

```
<html><body><tr class="table"><td class="table" valign="top"><p class="tbl-cod">0403</p></td><td class="table" valign="top"><p class="tbl-txt">Buttermilk, curdled milk and cream, yoghurt, kephir and other fermented or acidified milk and cream, whether or not concentrated or containing added sugar or other sweetening matter or flavoured or containing added fruit, nuts or cocoa</p></td><td class="table" valign="top"><p class="tbl-txt">Manufacture in which:—all the materials of Chapter 4 used are wholly obtained,—all the fruit juice (except that of pineapple, lime or grapefruit) of heading 2009 used is originating,and—the value of all the materials of Chapter 17 used does not exceed 30 % of the ex-works price of the product</p></td><td class="table" valign="top"><p class="normal"> </p></td></tr></body></html>
```

---

Now if you want to format again then try this

```
finalhtml=str(soup).replace('\n','')
soup=BeautifulSoup(finalhtml,'lxml')
print(soup.prettify(formatter=None))
```

**Output**:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <tr class="table">
   <td class="table" valign="top">
    <p class="tbl-cod">
     0403
    </p>
   </td>
   <td class="table" valign="top">
    <p class="tbl-txt">
     Buttermilk, curdled milk and cream, yoghurt, kephir and other fermented or acidified milk and cream, whether or not concentrated or containing added sugar or other sweetening matter or flavoured or containing added fruit, nuts or cocoa
    </p>
   </td>
   <td class="table" valign="top">
    <p class="tbl-txt">
     Manufacture in which:—all the materials of Chapter 4 used are wholly obtained,—all the fruit juice (except that of pineapple, lime or grapefruit) of heading 2009 used is originating,and—the value of all the materials of Chapter 17 used does not exceed 30 % of the ex-works price of the product
    </p>
   </td>
   <td class="table" valign="top">
    <p class="normal">
    </p>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this since weeks. Everything works perfectly. Just a naive question to be sure I understood how bs4 works: if I do not prettify the final HTML, would it be parsed and then scraped correctly, right? I mean, like the name suggests, '''.prettify()''' is just an aesthetic function for its readability?

Comment: @AleVesprini : yes you are right.If this resolved your problem please mark this as accepted by clicking on hollow under downvote button see this how you can do that https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers